# How to add view to remote view android notification

Tags: android

I want to create custom notification list in single notification.
For that I used remote view and in loop I have added other view.
But I can not see my nested view.
My code is,

```
public static void ShowNotification(ArrayList<ReminderNotification> arr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Logger.debug("size:" + arr.size());

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, mContext
                .getString(R.string.app_name), System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pluck_b);
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification);
        for (ReminderNotification obj : arr) {
            RemoteViews nested = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.notification);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext,
                    ToothBrushTimer.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                    0, notificationIntent, 0);
            nested.setOnClickPendingIntent(obj.getId(), contentIntent);
            nested.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
            nested.setTextViewText(R.id.title, mContext
                    .getString(R.string.app_name));
            nested.setTextViewText(R.id.text, obj.getName());
            contentView.addView(R.id.layout, nested);
        }
        notification.contentView = contentView;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, ToothBrushTimer.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Please help me to come out